# Two Way Mapping using single Data Structure

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, uuid

I ran across some code recently at work (recreated to be similar to what I am dealing with) similar to the code below

Is there a way I can rework the code below to use one data structure (with performance in mind)?

Here is some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
public class ObjectMapper {

    private Map<UUID,Integer> uuidMap;
    private Map<Integer,UUID> indexMap;

    public ObjectMapper(){
        uuidMap = new HashMap<UUID,Integer>();
        indexMap = new HashMap<Integer,UUID>();
    }

    public void addMapping(int index, UUID uuid){
        uuidMap.put(uuid, index);
        indexMap.put(index, uuid);
    }


    .
    .
    .

    public Integer getIndexByUUID(UUID uuid){
        return uuidMap.get(uuid);
    }

    public UUID getUUIDByIndex(Integer index){
        return indexMap.get(index);
    }


}
```

Comment: The existing approach of using a Map instance for each mapping seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711618/java-collection-unique-key-and-unique-value) with the recommendation to use BiMap from [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)

Comment: Cool.  I was really hoping for a way to do this without bringing in an outside Jar, though.  But that may not be possible.

Comment: If you look at BiMap's code, they use the double map to implement it, so I would say that it is the most obvious implementation, anyway. http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/StandardBiMap.java

Answer (score 2):

Apache collections supports a [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html) interface and a variety of fairly effective implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BiMap](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bimap/BiMap.html) from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

`BiMap` is a map that allows users to perform lookups from both directions. Both the keys and the values in a BiMap are unique.

The main implementation is `HashBiMap`.

**`inverse()`**

`BiMap.inverse()` returns a view where the position of the key type and value type are swapped.

```
MutableBiMap<Integer, String> biMap =
  HashBiMap.newWithKeysValues(1, "1", 2, "2", 3, "3");
MutableBiMap<String, Integer> inverse = biMap.inverse();
Assert.assertEquals("1", biMap.get(1));
Assert.assertEquals(1, inverse.get("1"));
Assert.assertTrue(inverse.containsKey("3"));
Assert.assertEquals(2, inverse.put("2", 4));
```

**`put()`**

`MutableBiMap.put()` behaves like `Map.put()` on a regular map, except it throws when a duplicate value is added.

```
MutableBiMap<Integer, String> biMap = HashBiMap.newMap();
biMap.put(1, "1"); // behaves like a regular put()
biMap.put(1, "1"); // no effect
biMap.put(2, "1"); // throws IllegalArgumentException
```

**`forcePut()`**

This behaves like `MutableBiMap.put()`, but it silently removes the map entry with the same value before putting the key-value pair in the map.

```
MutableBiMap<Integer, String> biMap = HashBiMap.newMap();
biMap.forcePut(1, "1"); // behaves like a regular put()
biMap.forcePut(1, "1"); // no effect
biMap.forcePut(1, "2"); // replaces the [1,"1"] pair with [1, "2"]
biMap.put(2, "2"); // removes the [1, "2"] pair before putting
Assert.assertFalse(biMap.containsKey(1));
Assert.assertEquals(HashBiMap.newWithKeysValues(2, "1"), biMap);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Comment: better than guava's

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single `Map<Object,Object>` to do both mappings. Ugly, sure. Performance should be roughly the same, or slightly better in the unlikely event that you have many `ObjectMapper`s with few mapped values.