# Use ImageIO.read for class extending BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, extends

(what people have against hello?)

I have a class which extends `BufferedImage`:

```
public class NamedImage extends BufferedImage{
    String name;
    public NamedImage(int width, int height, int imageType) {
        super(width, height, imageType);
    }
    public void setName(String text){
        name = text;
    }
}
```

Before I had this, I got my Images with:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(res);
```

Now, I want to translate this to `NamedImage`, but the following tries don't work:

```
NamedImage image = ImageIO.read(res);
NamedImage image = (NamedImage) ImageIO.read(res);
```

How can I achieve what I want to do? Why can't I cast a buffered image into a class, which extends this custom class?

(what people have against thank you?)

Comment: You cannot cast a parent class to a subclass in general. The image returned from `ImageIO` is a `BufferedImage` it does not know about your new class. Can you describe what you want to do with this new class and how it would be used?

Comment: Yes; my aim is to have an class which i can handle like an normal BufferedImage, but which i can give a name - for example image.setName("pic1"); I need this in my project to sort pics by a specific system, but that isnt important here.

Comment: `NamedImage` should have a constructor that accepts a `BufferedImage` and a `String`.  Alternately, add the images to a map that uses the name as key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility, if you want ImageIO to use your specific subclass. However, if all you want to do is give it a name, I'd probably use @AndrewThompsons suggestion with a `Map<String, BufferedImage>`, because it's less verbose.

```
ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(res);
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);

if (readers.hasNext()) {
    ImageReader reader = readers.next();
    reader.setInput(reader);

    int w = reader.getWidth(0);
    int h = reader.getHeight(0);

    ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

    NamedImage image = new NamedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    param.setDestination(image);

    /*image = (NamedImage)*/ reader.read(0, param);
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you for this. The problem with the hashmap is, i cannot get the keyfrom an image, only an image from the key. Or not? And second, i probably want to add more information then the name... so i would need something like an table... i think a class named "SpecialImage" s better for this.

Comment: For a bi-directional map, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/711625/1428606.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast an instance of a subclass to its parent class.
But you cannot cast  an instance of a superclass to a subclass

You can try to use solution something like this:

```
public class NamedImage extends BufferedImage {

    private String name;

    public NamedImage(BufferedImage img,String name){
        super(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),img.getType());
        setData(img.getData());
        this.name=name;
    }


    public NamedImage(int width, int height, int imageType) {
        super(width, height, imageType);

    }

    public void setName(String text) {
        name = text;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        NamedImage image = new NamedImage(ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/igor/Downloads/cats-coloring.gif")),"A cat");

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a word of caution here. The constructor in this case will allocate data for a new `BufferedImage` and copy the contents from the original, using twice the amount of memory needed. No problem for small images, but... You can fix this by using `super(img.getColorModel(), img.getRaster(), img.getColorModel().isAlphaPremultiplied(), null)` instead (and don't call `setData`).

Answer (score 2):

> How can I achieve what I want to do?

`NamedImage` should have a constructor that accepts a `BufferedImage` and a `String`.

Alternately, add the images to a map that uses the name as key. E.G.

```
BufferedImage bi = //...
String name = //...
HashMap<String, BufferedImage> images = HashMap<String, BufferedImage>();
images.add(name, bi);
```