# A Java multimap which allows fast lookup of key by value

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I have a multimap (like that provided by Guava):

```
Multimap<K, V>
```

which could be seen logically as:

```
Map<K, Set<V>>
```

The data in my multimap, has unique keys AND unique values.  i.e. There can never be the same value assigned to more than one key.

Aside from maintaining two Map structures, does anyone know of an existing class/api that might give me fast lookup by either key or value.

e.g.

```
Collection<V> get(K)

...and...

K getKeyByValue(V)
```

BTW, the Map MUST be mutable, i.e. my data is changing all the time. (For immutable Maps, Guava provides an ImmutableMultimap.inverse() which would solve this problem if my Map could be immutable.)

Any help would be apprecated.

Comment: Please check if this link solves the purpose? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711618/java-collection-unique-key-and-unique-value

Comment: Have you looked at Guava's BiMap? I think that's what you want here ... although, it is backed by two maps (something you seem to want to avoid).

Comment: Thanks, yes I have had a look at the BiMap.  However a BiMap is like  a plain old Map whereby you can lookup by Key or Value, however I'm after a "MultiMap".  i.e. whereby the value of the Map is a Set or List of values.

Comment: Guava does not expose a BiMultimap type, as demand hasn't been very high for such a structure and many of its users can settle for an immutable version.

Comment: [This issue (Many to Many relationship-based map)](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=394) is starred by 23 people, star / comment if you wish to see `BiMultimap` in Guava. However, as Louis said, [immutable inversed `Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html#inverse()) is sufficient for many use cases.

Comment: An immutable Multimap is not sufficient for the scenario I'm dealing with, as described in my original question.  Also, am only dealing with a one to many relationship.

Comment: This likely depends on the way your map is typically used. If V-to-K lookup speed is critical and the number of V per K is low enough, the obvious solution would be for each V to have a reference to its K, updated each time a (K,V) is added to the map or deleted from it (obviously, this should be done cleanly in OOP fashion). This makes V-to-K lookup O(1), but addition and deletion of (K,V) longer by O(|V|). Depending on the use case, it could be good or terrible.

Comment: If I were you I would create my own Multimap class with an internal map for the opposite lookup. The hard part that I would avoid if possible is allowing indirect modifications through returned views (keys(), keyset(), asMap(), etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;

public class MyMap<K, V> implements Multimap<K, V> {

    private Multimap<K, V> key2Value = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    private Map<V, K> value2key = Maps.newHashMap();

    public K getKeyByValue(V value) {
        return value2key.get(value);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return key2Value.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return key2Value.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return key2Value.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return key2Value.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsEntry(Object key, Object value) {
        return key2Value.containsEntry(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean put(K key, V value) {
        value2key.put(value, key);
        return key2Value.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object key, Object value) {
        value2key.remove(value);
        return key2Value.remove(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean putAll(K key, Iterable<? extends V> values) {
        for (V value : values) {
            value2key.put(value, key);
        }
        return key2Value.putAll(key, values);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean putAll(Multimap<? extends K, ? extends V> multimap) {
        for (Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : multimap.entries()) {
            value2key.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
        }
        return key2Value.putAll(multimap);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> replaceValues(K key, Iterable<? extends V> values) {
        Collection<V> replaced = key2Value.replaceValues(key, values);
        for (V value : replaced) {
            value2key.remove(value);
        }
        for (V value : values) {
            value2key.put(value, key);
        }
        return replaced;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> removeAll(Object key) {
        Collection<V> removed = key2Value.removeAll(key);
        for (V value : removed) {
            value2key.remove(value);
        }
        return removed;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        value2key.clear();
        key2Value.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> get(K key) {
        return key2Value.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return key2Value.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Multiset<K> keys() {
        return key2Value.keys();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return key2Value.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Entry<K, V>> entries() {
        return key2Value.entries();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<K, Collection<V>> asMap() {
        return key2Value.asMap();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyMap<String, String> map = new MyMap<>();

        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key1", "value2");
        map.put("key1", "value3");
        map.put("key1", "value4");
        map.put("key2", "value5");

        System.out.println(map.getKeyByValue("value1"));
        System.out.println(map.getKeyByValue("value5"));

    }

}
```

Out:

```
key1
key2
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you maybe need this class: **org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap**

it's ASF commons-collections.jar ,document: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html

Comment: Your answer does not solve my original stated problem.  In that I am after a multimap which allows fast lookup of keys by value.  The apache MultiValueMap does not provide lookup of keys by value.

Comment: i'm sorry didn't help you, but there have problem: a value maybe referenced by multiple key,  that will be very complicated ,more like many-to-many.