# Java unique value map

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I need a map with unique keys and also **storing** duplicate values only once. The interface will be the Map but I don't want that the *same* value use memory multiple times. For example:

In a normal Map implementation like HashMap suposing value.equals(value') and value.equals(value'') but value!=value' and value!=value' and value!=value'' if we:

```
put(key1, value);
put(key2, value');
put(key3, value'');
```

Then the value will be stored three times.

I tried to make my own implementation which looks like:

```
class MyMap2<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private Map<V, V> values;

    public MyMap2() {
        values = new HashMap<V, V>();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(final K key, final V value) {
        V v = values.get(value);
        if (v == null) {
            v = value;
            values.put(v, v);
        }
        return super.put(key, v);
    }
}
```

This implementation stores the value just one time (Please, note that I'm using the same value). But is there any *Map* which already implements this kind of data structure with get/put O(1)?

**Please, note that BiMap is not useful because it will cause an error in case of duplicated values.**

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to accomplish.  You're not storing copies of the object, you are storing multiple references to it. And, your implementation seems to just pass through to the super class .put() at the end anyhow?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? When you answer why you may realise that it is not really needed...

Comment: What about a case when two unique keys will have the same value. For example John and Bill, both are 20 years old?

Comment: You do not actually use much memory when you put the same values to the map. You are not copying objects. So feel free to use just HashMap

Comment: I don't believe this question is asking the same thing as the question it's marked as a duplicate of.  But that's just my take.

Comment: I need to use this kind of implementation for example in case that I have two equal values:

`code` `code`

Comment: "This implementation stores the value just one time" - this is not correct. I've run that code with `mymap.put("hello","world")` and `mymap.put("hi","world")` and both key-value pairs were stored. Your code is not doing what you want.

Comment: Ok, this question really needs rewording. If if get you right, you have an issue storing objects with different references (different objects), but that have the same "value" (as in internal member variables). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct!

Comment: Ok, I get you now. But your code still doesn't do it. I still see multiple references from objects that are equal (I tested for equality before putting both).

Comment: The references are not a problem for me, the problem is the size of stored objects.

Comment: If the references are not the same you are storing multiple copies of the objects. I just double-checked, `values.get(value)` always returns `null` even when the value is supposed to be already in the map. Even after overriding `equals` on the class being tested. This is actually weird.

Comment: If you test the following code, it will enter just two times in v == null condition:
`
map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key2","value1");
map.put("key2","value2");
`

Comment: Don't use String as values for your tests. Create a Person class and do `new Person("name")`. Then create `person1`, `person2`, `person3` all with the same name. Then add them all to your map with different keys. They 3 persons may have the same name (you can even override `equals` to ensure that `person1.equals(person2)` but your map will be storing different objects (3x the memory), not multiple references to the same object (1x the memory).

Comment: If you override the method equals it will work for you also the hashcode method

Comment: Yup. You need to override both `equals` and `hashCode` then it will work.

Comment: Any better implementation?

Comment: Not that I know. The fact that you need to override those 2 methods in order for it to work means that it's not the kind of thing you'll find in a common library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation **already** promises constant time get/put operations. The worst case is when inserting a new value that has never been seen yet. In this case you will:

1. Attempt to find the value in the `values` map - O(1), since it's a `HashMap`.
2. Not find it, and put the value in the `values` map - O(1), since it's a `HashMap`.
3. Put the key-value pair in `super` - O(1), since it's a `HashMap`.

You find a better way of implementing this logic, but not by an order of magnitude.

EDIT:
Note that the implementation may `put` in `super` twice, which is just redundant. It can be tweaked to be slightly cleaner:

```
@Override
public V put(final K key, final V value) {
    V v = values.get(value);
    if (v == null) {
        v = value
        values.put(v, v);
    } 
    return super.put(key, v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you with super.put(), but is there any another possible implementation which doesn't use a Map<V,V> (like"Map<V>" to avoid store two times the same value?

Comment: In the case of `put(v,v)` you're storing only the reference to v (not 2 copies), so although not elegant it's not inneficient in terms of memory.

Comment: So my question is: Is there any more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This was already asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711618/java-collection-unique-key-and-unique-value).

Check out [BiMap](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Comment: The OP's example of putting the same object for 3 keys would throw an IllegalArgumentException using a BiMap

Comment: As FatalError said in this case the BiMap is not useful

Comment: In the question you didn't specify what 's the desired behaviour when you store the same value. The code isn't clear to me either. At a first glance it seems like it still stores duplicate values. `super.put(key, value)` does exactly the same as  `super.put(key, v)` since `value == v`.

Comment: Please, note that value' equals value'' but is not the same object so it will be stored in memory multiple times.