# How to produce map with distinct values from a map (and use the right key using BinaryOperator)?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a map `Map<K, V>` and my goal is to remove the duplicated values and output the very same structure `Map<K, V>` again. In case the duplicated value is found, there must be selected one key (`k`) from the two keys (`k1` and `k2`) which hold these values, for this reason, assume the `BinaryOperator<K>` giving `k` from `k1` and `k2` is available.

Example input and output:

```
// Input
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "apple");
map.put(5, "apple");
map.put(4, "orange");
map.put(3, "apple");
map.put(2, "orange");

// Output: {5=apple, 4=orange} // the key is the largest possible
```

My attempt using [`Stream::collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) is <strike>a bit</strike> very clumsy and contains mutable operations such as `Map::put` and `Map::remove` which I would like to avoid:

```
// // the key is the largest integer possible (following the example above)
final BinaryOperator<K> reducingKeysBinaryOperator = (k1, k2) -> k1 > k2 ? k1 : k2;

Map<K, V> distinctValuesMap = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
    HashMap::new,                                                              // A new map to return (supplier)
    (map, entry) -> {                                                          // Accumulator
        final K key = entry.getKey();
        final V value = entry.getValue();
        final Entry<K, V> editedEntry = Optional.of(map)                       // New edited Value
            .filter(HashMap::isEmpty)
            .map(m -> new SimpleEntry<>(key, value))                           // If a first entry, use it
            .orElseGet(() -> map.entrySet()                                    // otherwise check for a duplicate
                    .stream() 
                    .filter(e -> value.equals(e.getValue()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(                               // .. if found, replace
                            reducingKeysBinaryOperator.apply(e.getKey(), key), 
                            map.remove(e.getKey())))
                    .orElse(new SimpleEntry<>(key, value)));                   // .. or else leave
        map.put(editedEntry.getKey(), editedEntry.getValue());                 // put it to the map
    },
    (m1, m2) -> {}                                                             // Combiner
);
```

**Is there a solution using an appropriate combination of [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) within one `Stream::collect` call (e.g. without mutable operations)?**

Comment: What is your metrics for "*better*" or "*best*"? Must ist be done through `Stream`s?

Comment: If the same value is associated with 2 keys, how do you choose which key is retained?

Comment: What are the expected output in your case?

Comment: @YCF_L: The very same as sample input-output above my attempt.

Comment: @Turing85: As I said. The *better* or the *best* would be with no explicit use of mutable map methods such as `Map::put` or `Map::remove` within the `Collector`.

Comment: @Michael: I said it in the question - the `BinaryOperator<KEY>` assures it.

Comment: It's worth taking a look at [`BiMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711618/java-collection-unique-key-and-unique-value). Possibly a duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812454/remove-duplicate-values-from-hashmap-in-java)

Comment: Not a bad idea. I take a look. However, I am not a fan of Guava or Apache Commons. Moreover, I believe there is a simple solution using what JDK offers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator))

```
private Map<Integer, String> deduplicateValues(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    Map<String, Integer> inverse = map.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Math::max) // take the highest key on duplicate values
    );

    return inverse.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this: Simple way is inverse the key and value then use `toMap()` collector with merge function.

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, reducingKeysBinaryOperator));
```

---

```
Map<K, V> output = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey, reducingKeysBinaryOperator))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

Comment: I fail to see what the intermediate `map` operation buys. You seem to swap keys and values, that much is clear, but what is the point, you could do that at the collect step just the same ?

Comment: @GPI and Michael, this is because he has to merge the keys, so invert the pairs will merge the keys. What is missing is the second inversion then.

Comment: @HadiJ No! Inversion was correct! but a second one was necessary to get back. Merge is used to merge the keys, but merging is only possible for values...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I understand the need to merge, but why I don't immediatly get is why you code `swap(); collect(key, value, binOp);`instead of `collect(value, key, binOp)`. Maybe I need to try this in a jshell for real ?

Comment: Took the liberty to use the local variable introduced in the question in the code-shared by you. Do revert in case it conflicts the intention while you were making the answer.

Comment: Simple and straightforward! Works like charm :) Is it possible to achieve the very same result with no process-collect-process pipeline (within one `Stream`)?

Answer (score 4):

I find the non-streams solution more expressive:

```
BinaryOperator<K> reducingKeysBinaryOperator = (k1, k2) -> k1 > k2 ? k1 : k2;

Map<V, K> reverse = new LinkedHashMap<>(map.size());
map.forEach((k, v) -> reverse.merge(v, k, reducingKeysBinaryOperator));

Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(reverse.size());
reverse.forEach((v, k) -> result.put(k, v));
```

This uses [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) with your reducing bi-function and uses `LinkedHashMap` to preserve original entries order.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of using only `Collectors` with no need for collecting and further processing the returned Map again. The idea is:

1. Group the `Map<K, V>` to `Map<V, List<K>`.

   ```
   Map<K, V> distinctValuesMap = this.stream.collect(
       Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue),
           groupingDownstream 
       )
   );
   ```

   > {apple=[1, 5, 3], orange=[4, 2]}
2. Reduce the new keys (`List<K>`) to `K` using `BinaryOperator<K>`.

   ```
   Function<Entry<V, List<Entry<K, V>>>, K> keyMapFunction = e -> e.getValue().stream()
       .map(Entry::getKey)
       .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.reducing(reducingKeysBinaryOperator),
           Optional::get
       )
   );
   ```

   > {apple=5, orange=4}
3. Inverse the `Map<V, K>` back to `Map<K, V>` structure again - which is safe since both keys and values are guaranteed as distinct.

   ```
   Function<Map<V, List<Entry<K,V>>>, Map<K, V>> groupingDownstream = m -> m.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
           keyMapFunction,
           Entry::getKey
       )
   );
   ```

   > {5=apple, 4=orange}

The final code:

```
final BinaryOperator<K> reducingKeysBinaryOperator = ...

final Map<K, V> distinctValuesMap = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue),
            m -> m.entrySet().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Entry::getKey).collect(
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.reducing(reducingKeysBinaryOperator),
                            Optional::get
                        )
                    ),
                    Entry::getKey
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approch to get the desired result with "Stream and Collectors.groupingBy".

```
    map = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Entry::getValue,
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey))
            )
    )
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            k -> {
                return k.getValue().get().getKey();
            }, 
            Entry::getKey));
```